# Gradle: Custom task with parameter set programmatically

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the following scenario where I wish to **disable** JOOQ Schema generation unless explicitly called for:

```
gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask {
    task ->
        if (!rootProject.hasProperty("generate") && task.name.equals("generateSampleJooqSchemaSource")) {
            task.enabled = false
        }
}
```

Now I can always manually generate the schema when passing "generate" as a parameter as follows:

```
$ gradle build -Pgenerate
```

Whereas a normal

```
$ gradle build
```

would **not** regenerate all my schema classes.

However, I do not like this approach very much. You have to remember the parameter name, and also prepend it with `-P` which does not look as clean.

I would ideally like to be able to make a custom task as follows:

```
task generate {
    tasks[build].executeWithParameter("generate")
}
```

So that it would also show up as an actual task.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a task that `dependsOn` build task and disable jooq task from it. This requires the task declaration to be put after jooq task declaration.

```
task generate (dependsOn: build) {
    tasks['generateSampleJooqSchemaSource'].enabled = false
}
```

to set project property from task

```
task generate (dependsOn: build) {
    project.ext.generate = "true"
}
```

Comment: This is not quite what I was asking - the `taskGraph` example above already disables the task as I wished it to. What I want is a task that simulates a parameter being passed (i.e. `-Pgenerate`) and then calls the `build` task normally.

Comment: @user991710 I added the example. Build task is still called via dependsOn. Also you can use finalizedBy.